# How to save a reference to a previous version of an object in mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to get started with MongoDB. I am used to working with relational database engines but now I have to work with MongoDB per requirement.

I am trying to explain my general problem as simplified as possible. Imagine being a `Person`. You have some traits like a  name or some friends. Now you have died of old age and been born as a new human. You now could have a different name and different friends.

Now you don't like your new "You" and want to return to a previous version of yourself, maybe because you liked the name or the friends more.

To allow this, a `Person` is bound to a `Soul` which just stores the current `Person` as well as all your previous ones.

Now when you store this object in MongoDB you get pretty fast a very huge document (More than 13k Lines in my case). I have created a similar JSON structure to highlight the problem.

```
    "Souls:" {
        "UniqueId": {
            "CurrentPerson": {
                "Name": "Jane Doe",
                "PreviousLifePerson": {
                    "Name": "John Doe",
                    "PreviousLifePerson": {
                        "Name": "Max Mustermann",
                        "PreviousLifePerson": {
                            "Name": "Erika Mustermann",
                            "PreviousLifePerson": null 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have read that MongoDB saves related objects as embedded document by default.
The solution to this problem will probably be to save relations by the id of an object. However I am still unsure on if this is really the best solution and additionally I have some questions about general best practices for the .NET MongoDB Driver.

In C# I would propably have a class like this then:

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Friends")]
        public List<ObjectId> FriendIds { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }


        [BsonElement("Reincarnation")]
        public int Reincarnation { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("PreviousLifePerson")]
        public ObjectId PreviousLifePersonId { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        public Person PreviousLifePerson { get; set; }
    }
```

1. For each Ignored Element I'd have to send an additionally query to the database and retrieve those elements. Is this right?
2. Would I have for `Soul` and `Person` an individual collection then, even if a person is always assigned to a soul?
3. There surely is no built-in way to deserialize an object from the database without explicitly specifying the object id as a property, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this is a highly relational problem domain, i would do it with [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) convenience library. here's a full program covering all the bases you mentioned.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Soul : Entity
        {
            public Many<Person> Incarnations { get; set; }
            public One<Person> CurrentIncarnation { get; set; }

            public Soul() => this.InitOneToMany(() => Incarnations);
        }

        public class Person : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public One<Soul> Soul { get; set; }
            public One<Person> PreviousLife { get; set; }
            public Many<Person> Friends { get; set; }
            public bool IsDead { get; set; } = false;

            public Person() => this.InitOneToMany(() => Friends);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            //big bang
            var god = new Soul();
            god.Save();


            //first man is born
            var adam = new Person
            {
                Name = "Adam",
                Soul = god.ToReference()
            };
            adam.Save();
            god.Incarnations.Add(adam);
            god.CurrentIncarnation = adam.ToReference();

            //first woman is born (without a soul ;p)
            var eve = new Person
            {
                Name = "Eve",
            };
            eve.Save();

            //adam and eve become friends under an apple tree
            adam.Friends.Add(eve);
            eve.Friends.Add(adam);

            //adam dies and comes back as sally
            adam.IsDead = true; adam.Save();
            var sally = new Person
            {
                Name = "Sally",
                Soul = god.ToReference(),
                PreviousLife = adam.ToReference()
            };
            sally.Save();
            god.CurrentIncarnation = sally.ToReference();
            god.Incarnations.Add(sally);

            //sally and eve feel a deep connection
            sally.Friends.Add(eve);

            //sally feels stuck in a mans body, so she goes back to being adam
            sally.IsDead = true;
            sally.Save();
            god.CurrentIncarnation = adam.ToReference();
            god.Save();
            adam.IsDead = false;
            adam.PreviousLife = sally.ToReference();
            adam.Save();

            //invite sally's friends to the funeral
            var guestlist = DB.Find<Person>().One(sally.ID)
                                             .Friends.Collection()
                                             .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

the library stores relationships by using special join collections which are automatically indexed which makes queries extremely fast.

my personal rule of thumb is to not embed an object inside another if there's gonna be more than a handful of them in there. but it all depends on how your app queries the data, what data is needed by your apps views. with MongoDB.Entities you have the freedom to do both quite easily.